# Decoding in VHDL - Bit masking

Tags: vhdl, programming

I'm searching for the optimal way to do this in VHDL:

```
"000" -> -------1
"001" -> ------1-
"010" -> -----1--
"011" -> ----1---
"100" -> ---1----
"101" -> --1-----
"110" -> -1------
"111" -> 1-------
```

Is there a better way to do this than an big switch(case)? I was told to use a for loop but I fail to see how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out. I needed a break, here's what I do to make this more elegant:

```
for i in 0 to 7 loop
     if (i = unsigned(rx_data(7 downto 5))) then
           cs_o(i) <= '1';
     end if;
end loop ;
```

`rx_data(7 downto 5)` being the 3 bits that need to be encoded into the `cs_o` byte.

**[EDIT]**
Or even better (credits to A. Kieffer) :

```
cs_o(to_integer(unsigned(rx_data(7 downto 5)))) <= '1';
```

This transforms a 20+ lines switch statement into 1. wow

Comment: What about `cs_o(to_integer(unsigned(rx_data(7 downto 5)))) <= '1'; ` ?

Comment: Also, don't you need something to set the other bits to `'0'`?

Comment: No that is actually the point! I want the other bits to stay at their previous state
To put this in context, it's an 8 bit chip select word. Every bit of this word drives a module, I don't want other modules going off when one is triggered.

@A. Kieffer: Why is it better? 
EDIT: Oh didn't read that properly, gonna try!

Comment: @Fluff'n'Stuff But once they are triggered they are never reset. Don't you need something to trigger them off?

Comment: This goes in a process triggered by the states of a state machine, i'm resetting this elsewhere!

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a barrel shifter. They are used in floating point units, or anywhere where a programmable shift register is required. 
[image: barrel shifter]

It requires two for loops because you create a matrix of multiplexers.

On the other hand, if you want to generate your pattern you can load 1 in a variable and keep shifting until you get your required number. There are many ways to implement that, depending on the required performance e.g. Shift register + counter.

Edit
I should also add that if you just want to generate your pattern, you can create an array of constants and assign it in a process. This is where you use your for loop. Your question is somewhat unclear on exactly what you want to achieve. I mean a constant output of all 1's will satisfy your don't cares.

Comment: You're right this should be more detailed. What I'm trying to achieve is a process that will trigger '1' without affecting any other bit of the word, depending on the command it receives. In the end, this 8-bit word drives 8 different modules, one bit each, that determines whether it is selected or not.
My solution seems to be working fine, but I didn't now about this shifter, thanks for the effort

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it as a process or a function. My example uses a function, which can be reused.

The function is defined in the [utils](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/utils.vhdl#L928-L935) package of our [PoC-Library](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC). The packages  also contains the reverse transformation and other binary <=> xxx encodings.

**Function:**

```
-- Binary-Code to One-Hot-Code
function bin2onehot(Value : std_logic_vector) return std_logic_vector is
    variable result     : std_logic_vector(2**Value'length - 1 downto 0);
begin
    result  := (others => '0');
    result(to_integer(unsigned(Value, 0))) := '1';
    return result;
end function;
```

*Note: The result is initialized in the function's body, so it works with Altera Quartus, too.*

**Usage:**

```
signal bin    : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
signal onehot : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
...
onehot <= bin2onehot(bin);
```

Source: [PoC.utils](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/utils.vhdl#L928-L935) package